# How to burn Arduino Bootloader on ATmega168PA-PU?

Tags: arduino-uno

How can I burn the Arduino Bootloader on an ATmega168PA-PU with an Arduino Uno?

Answer (score 2):

I have a bootloader-programmer sketch here:

http://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader

Basically you connect up the boards like this:

```
Arduino Uno         Target ATmega168PA

D10 (SS)            Reset (pin 1)
D11 (MOSI)          MOSI  (pin 17)
D12 (MISO)          MISO  (pin 18)
D13 (SCK)           SCK   (pin 19)

Gnd                 Gnd   (pins 8 & 22)
+5V                 +5V   (pins 7 & 20)
```

Then download the sketch from [GitHub](https://github.com/nickgammon/arduino_sketches) - the one you want is in the **Atmega_Board_Programmer** folder. Run that and follow the instructions in the Serial Monitor.

For more information see the link above.

Answer (score 1):

The official Arduino documentation has detailed instructions on how to transform Arduino board into an ISP.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP